# How can I enable Wayland's autorotation in Plasma 6?

Tags: linux, kde, opensuse, wayland, kde-plasma-workspace

I've recently updated from KDE 5 to KDE 6 on OpenSUSE Tumbleweed on a convertible (Lenovo Thinkpad X390 Yoga). Before the update, the automatic screen rotation in "tablet mode" (apparently renamed to "touch mode" in KDE/Plasma 6) worked fine. But now, there's not even an option in the display settings anymore.

Is there a way to re-enable that feature?

`iio-sensor-proxy` is installed, and `monitor-sensor` reports the display rotation correctly.

Answer (score 0):

While I can't find the patch notes for the changes, another `zypper dup && reboot`<sup>1</sup> four days later fixed the issue. Seems like this was just some quirk of the early release days of KDE/Plasma 6.

<sub>1: Another `zypper dup` last Sunday didn't
t fix the issue, so the patch has been released between 2024-03-24 and 2024-03-27 (UTC).</sub>